# Ajax not working in retrieving data (CAKEPHP)

Tags: ajax, cakephp

Here's my code:
This is javascript file that sends the get the selected element from view and send that id to the controller as an Ajax request.

```
function getData (id, e) {

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {

        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {

        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    }

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

        if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {

            alert('yes');
        }else{

            alert('no');
        }
    }

    xmlHttp.open('POST', '/BrandDetail/returnPdetails', true);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xmlHttp.send(id);
    e.preventDefault();

}
});
```

Now here's the controller that is not either getting the request or responding it.

```
class BrandDetailController extends AppController {

public $name = 'BrandDetail';

 function returnPdetails () {

    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $data = $this->brandDetail->find('all', array('conditions' => array('brandDetail.id' => $id)));
}
}
```

Comment: 1) don't include all the excess CSS code, 2) what is your actual question 3) is there an error of some kind - what is happening, what isn't...etc

Answer (score 1):

1. You should be calling the controller from your ajax submit not the model. Pluralize your path to

   xmlHttp.open('POST', '/BrandDetails/returnPdetails', true);
2. The parameters being passed in the send function should be keys and values

   xmlHttp.send("id="+id);
3. You are not actually sending any data or strings out to the view for your ajax response. In your controller, at least send a test string to the view before trying to manipulate data that you are unsure is even making it to the controller.

   function returnPdetails(){

   $id = $this->params['named']['id'];

   $data = $this->BrandDetail->findById($id);

   pr('Some text to test if the request is working');
   }
4. The readystatechange function shouldn't be capitalized according to [here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp%20here)

   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange
5. Narrow down your issues by catching the errors in your  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange function. Put in statements if the readyState is 0, 1, 2, or 3 as well. This will help you debug.